# iis 6 and asp.net cookieless session, record session ID in iis log

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, logging, cookieless

In a website that uses asp.net cookieless session, what is the best way to have the session id recorded in the IIS log files?

For example, if the client requests a page

http://server.tld/(S(kdcwx1552av4iq45uabwa145))/site.aspx

by default, IIS only records

```
cs-uri-stem 
/site.aspx
```

in its log-files, i.e. the session id is not recorded (though it may appear in the referrer field).

Is there any build in way to include the session id in the log? 
If not, I guess a custom ISAPI filter would work?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the only way to record the session ID would be to record it manually. You could try using:

```
Response.AppendToLog()
```

Comment: Thanks, I added something to that extent to Application_AcquireRequestState, seems to work well enough